# Pyhton Sellenium no such element TD

Tags: python, selenium

estoy haciendo scraping con Sellenium. Puedo clickear todo sin problema, pero llegue a una tabla la cual no me reconoce el clik. El error que me sale es:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":

MI código es:

```
Driver.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

El html es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]